# Unable to mock POST request with nock

Tags: jestjs, nock

I'm using the fetch API and nock to mock a post request. The test looks like so:

```
it('should handle the triple bracket replacements ', async () => {
  nock('https://jives.dev')
    .post('/', {
      bestCat: 'cat'
    })
    .reply(200, {
      data: '12345'
    })

  const data = await retrieveData({
    endpoint: 'https://jives.dev/',
    configuration: JSON.stringify({
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        bestCat: 'cat'
      }
    }),
    auth: {cat: 'cat'}
  })

  expect(data).toEqual({data: '12345'})
})
```

The `retrieveData` function runs `fetch`, and simply maps the endpoint and configuration args into a request as following:

```
fetch('https://jives.dev/', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    bestCat: 'cat'
  }
})
```

I end up getting an error as if nock is not mocking the request. I can get it to work for `get` requests but I'm unsure why this isn't working in this example. The error message looks like it's trying to actually make the post request instead of returning data from nock.

```
- Expected  - 3
+ Received  + 1

- Object {
-   "data": "12345",
- }
+ [Error]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by me not cleaning all of the mocks in the jest suite. The following resolved this.

```
afterEach(nock.cleanAll)
afterAll(nock.restore)
```